# Rails conventional render partial with objects within a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

I would like to locate a partial in the app/views dir to be shared by two name spaces. How can I link the missing partials, (lostees or others)/trees/tree.html.haml to trees/tree.html.haml using Rails convention shown in the islands/show.html.haml example?

config/routes.rb

```
namespace :lostees do
  resources :islands
end

namespace :others do
  resources :islands
end
```

app/controllers/lostees/islands_controller.rb

```
class Lostees::IslandsController < Lostees::BaseController
end
```

app/controllers/others/islands_controller.rb

```
class Others::IslandsController < Others::BaseController
end
```

app/views/trees/_tree.html.haml

```
= content_tag_for tree do
  = tree.name
```

app/views/lostees/islands/show.html.haml

```
%h2 The Island

%div Trees
= render island.trees

#=> Missing partial lostees/trees/tree
```

app/views/others/islands/show.html.haml

```
%h2 The Island

%div Trees
= render island.trees

#=> Missing partial others/trees/tree
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably figured this out already, but you should be able to do this with:

```
= render partial: "trees/tree", collection: island.trees
```

Comment: That seems to be the only way to do this. Just wondering if there was a way to stick with rails convention/short cuts.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of would be to look into the load paths that Rails is looking through to find the partial. I'm assuming you don't have a TreesController, otherwise I would expect it to look for trees/_tree.html.haml. However, if both of your Basecontrollers inherit from ApplicationController, you might be able to put the partial in application/_tree.html.haml and see if Rails finds it there. I don't know if this will work for sure, but it might.